# Prove that the average velocity over an interval is the average of instantaneous velocities without calculus

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

I am re-reading my old first semester Physics textbook and came across the well known formula that for a particle in *constant* acceleration $a_x$ from time $0$ to time $t$ $$v_{av-x}=\frac{1}{2}\left(v_{0x}+v_x\right)$$ where $v_{av-x}$ is the average velocity of the particle over the interval from $0$ to $t$, $v_{0x}$ is the instantaneous initial velocity, and $v_x$ is the instantaneous velocity at time $t$. It's important to note that $v_{av-x}$ is defined as $\Delta x/\Delta t$, where $\Delta x$ is the displacement of the particle.

Clearly this can be justified with calculus using the formula $v_{av-x}=\frac{1}{t-0}\int_0^t v_x(t)\space dt$, but it seems one should be able to prove this for the constant acceleration case using algebra only, no? Of course, I thought about the "area under the $v_xt$ graph" as a way to prove this, but that's calculus in disguise.

Is there any neat way to prove this without calculus or resorting to the handwaivy "average of a linearly varying quantity" argument?

Comment: How are you defining the instantaneous velocity of a particle, if not using calculus?

Comment: @csch2 indeed with derivatives.

Comment: I guess a way to derive that kinematic formula is by considering the velocity graph for a particle with constant acceleration (AKA a constant slope) that starts with an initial velocity $v_0$. The total area $\Delta x$ (displacement) can be calculated using the formulas for the area of a rectangle and the area of a right triangle. In a way, maybe it's considered calculus in disguise to you, though.

Comment: IMO, if the acceleration is constant the following equation must hold $$\frac{\overline v}{2}\left(t_{0}+t_x\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(v_{0}+v_x\right),$$
where $\overline v$ is the average velocity on the interval $[0,x]$.

Comment: @callculus42, the equation you've proposed cannot be correct: its LHS has dimension of distance, whereas its RHS has dimension of velocity.

Comment: @Gonçalo Oh yes, I see now. It is totally nonsense. OMG. Your answer, in contrast, look good.

Answer (score 1):

For constant acceleration $a_x$, the displacement $x(t)$ and the instantaneous velocity $v_x(t)$ are given by
\begin{align}
x(t)&=x_0+v_{0x}t+\frac{1}{2}a_xt^2, \\
v_x(t)&=v_{0x}+a_xt.
\end{align}
Therefore, using the definition of $v_{av-x}$, one has
$$
v_{av-x}=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\frac{x(t)-x(0)}{t-0}=v_{0x}+\frac{1}{2}a_xt=
\frac{v_{0x}+v_x(t)}{2}.
$$